# How to map a global key to refresh?

Tags: firefox, refresh, autohotkey

Winamp has a neat feature. **Global keys.** That way I can change the playing song even if Winamp GUI doesn't have focus.

I am looking for a **similar solution to Firefox or Chrome**.

I use Eclipse to code PHP.
It auto SSH's and saves to another machine (testing)
I could use something like [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/#features) with a mapped virtual drive but I cant install Samba on the testing machine.

**Right now I have to:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (save and auto-update)
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (switch to Firefox GUI)
<kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh current Firefox page)
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (back to Eclipse)

**I am looking for something like:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (save and auto-update)
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (refresh Firefox - while keeping focus on Eclipse)

I've looked over Firefox Plug-ins but found nothing to my needs. Chrome neither. XRefresh would be a perfect solution but, as said, cant SSH/Samba into the testing machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)

Let me add my result for the awesome.ahc file:

```
^s::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Mozilla Firefox
{
   WinActivate, Mozilla Firefox
   ControlSend, ahk_parent, {F5}, Mozilla Firefox
}
Return
```

This will switch to firefox and refresh the currently active tab.

Comment: demoncodemonkey this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As demoncodemonkey greatly suggested you can use Autohotkey. This is my script sample.

```
^x::                  ; listen for a CTRL+x
   Send ^s               ; sends a CTRL+s save command to Eclipse
   Sleep 500             ; sleeps a bit to allow SSH to transfer file
   Send !{tab}^r         ; alt-tab followed by a browser refresh
   Sleep 100             ; firefox, needs just a bit to allow ALT-TAB
   Send !{tab}           ; tabs back to eclipse
```

This is even better than I had in mind as I can do it all with only a single command. Very impressive. Thanks again demoncodemonkey.

Comment: Nice. I probably would have used the WinActivate function instead because your script won't work if you have just Alt+Tabbed to a different window. But I guess it will work most of the time. BTW once you start with AHK there is no going back :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Frankie's answer, I developed something a bit more advanced. My editor is Aptana, but you can easily change it into anything else:

```
$^s::                                       ; only capture actual keystrokes
SetTitleMatchMode, 2                        ; match anywhere in the title
IfWinActive, Aptana Studio 3                ; find aptana
{
    Send ^s                                 ; send save command
    IfWinExist, Mozilla Firefox             ; find firefox
    {
        WinActivate                         ; use the window found above
        Sleep 500                           ; sleeps to allow SSH to transfer file
        Send ^r                             ; send browser refresh
        WinActivate, Aptana Studio 3        ; get back to Aptana
    }
}
else
{
    Send ^s                                 ; send save command
}
return
```